# Do/while doesn't work with not equals

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

My do/while doesn't work for some reason, I have a feeling that it doesn't notice the `!rep`, it just loops for any char I enter. I tried only putting `!rep.toUpperCase().equals("O")` and it worked, but I want the N also.

```
if (utilisateurDansListe(user) == true) {
    do {
        System.out.println("Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer " + user
                           + "?" + " O-Oui ou N-Non");
        rep = sc.next();
    } while (!rep.toUpperCase().equals("O")
             || !rep.toUpperCase().equals("N"));
    if (rep.toUpperCase().equals("O")) {
        monApp.listeUtilisateurs.remove(utilisateurChoisi);
        System.out.println("Utilisateur supprimer avec succes !");
    } else
        System.out.println(user + " n'a pas ete supprimer");
} else
    System.out.println("Utilisateur inexistant");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong. You want:

```
while (!rep.toUpperCase().equals("O") && !rep.toUpperCase().equals("N"));
```

That is, you want to loop to run while the answer *(is not `O`) and (is not `N`)*. You can also flip the logic:

```
while (!(rep.toUpperCase().equals("O") || rep.toUpperCase().equals("N")));
```

Run while the answer *is not (`O` or `N`)*.

Comment: Oh, damn, that was a stupid mistake ahah, thanks alot ! I told myself that i wanted it to loop if the answer wasnt either O or N thats why

Answer (score 1):

Your boolean logic here is causing the problem -

```
while (!rep.toUpperCase().equals("O") || !rep.toUpperCase().equals("N"));
```

Here you are essentially saying, "While `sc.next()` is `not 'O'` or `not 'N'` - keep looping". The problem is that `sc.next()` can never fulfill both conditions of Not being 'O' OR Not being 'N'. Instead use the AND condition like so:

```
while (!rep.toUpperCase().equals("O") && !rep.toUpperCase().equals("N"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Your condition *is* always true.
Any String is *always* either *not* "N" or *not* "O".